# How can I upload file with FileUpload1 control asynchronously in ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-code, file-upload, webforms

My problem is that when I click on Upload button it gives no reaction because `FileUpload1` is empty.

Upload button:

```
<asp:Button ID="UpLoad_Button" runat="server" 
     OnClick="UpLoad_Button_Click" Text="Upload" 
     BorderColor="black" BorderStyle="Dashed" />
```

Code behind:

```
if (FileUpload1.HasFile == true)
{
    extension = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName);
    StreamReader readTextFile = new StreamReader(FileUpload1.FileContent, Encoding.UTF8);

    TextBox1.Text = readTextFile.ReadToEnd();
}
```

FileUpload control:

```
<asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" 
     BorderColor="Silver" BorderStyle="None" 
     Height="30px" Width="189px" 
     onchange="UpLoad_Button_Click"/>
```

Comment: Are you saying that WHEN the user selects a file, then FileUpload1.HasFile REMAINS false and is not working? Or are you asking how to deal with when the user hits your up-load button but not yet having selected a file? it not clear from your question if you are expecting the FileUpload to "has a file", or that when you select a file, hasFile remains false and is not working? Remember standard file upload control can't be placed inside of a update panel. So, are you asking what to do when user has not selected a file, or are you asking why your code not working?

Comment: First user clicks on a FileUpload1 control to browse/select file than clicks on an Upload Button but does not work only when use a PostBackTrigger but with AsyncPostBackTrigger is not working...

Comment: That is because the FileUpload control needs a full PostBack. It does not work async in webforms.

Comment: there is no workaround?

Comment: Yes, there are workarounds - and one way is to use file chunking, and send only a small part of the file. This has the added bonus of up-loading files of un-limited size. See answer below for such examples. However, you MOST certainly did leave out of your markup the fact that you are using a up-date panel and thus get an award for confusing the hell out of everyone here.

Answer (score 0):

There are BOATLOADS of file up-loaders available for free that do NOT require a post-back (and thus are asynchronous).

You could also I suppose roll your own up-loader, but that can be a bit of work.

I use the free one from the AjaxToolkit.

Now, to be fair, the AjaxToolkit is a rather large library to adopt JUST for a nice asynchronous up-loader (one that does not require a post-back by the way).

However, the AJ kit also has a HTML editor, and also does have a nice dialog popup extender. And it has a multi-select combo box (dropdown list). So, if you need some of these other features, then the AJ toolkit is a great free choice.

You can find it here:

https://www.devexpress.com/Products/AJAX-Control-Toolkit/

(it is open source, and free - and is currently maintained by DevExpress).

And there is file pond, again a nice up-loader and free.

So, the advantage of these up-loaders:

```
No post-back is required to up-load a file
They have a hot-zone (drag and drop files) area
They have a nice progress bar DURING up-load
They allow multiple files
They have options to set/restrict the allowable file extensions.
File size is un-limited, since file is up-loaded in chunks.
```

So, here is an example from the AjaxToolKit up-loader

[image]

So, you can use select file, or drag and drop as above shows.

And as noted, there is no post-back here.

So the standard HTML file upload control? Yes, it needs a full page post-back to work correctly, and thus it does not work inside of a update panel.

The above AjaxFileUpLoader should work inside of a update panel, but then again, since it can upload files - even multiple files selected (or drag + dropped into the hot zone), then no post-back occurs, and thus there is little need for using a update-panel anyway.

As noted, it also has a rather nice progress bar (user will not think the browser is frozen or stuck). And during the up-load, the user can hit cancel to stop the upload, and again that's another good reason to use some type of uploading library. (it is more user friendly).

As noted, you can try and roll your own, but these days, there are quite a few free examples of ajax (asynchronous) up-loaders that don't require a post-back, and they tend to result in a far better user experience then using the standard HTML file upload control.

## Edit: User does not want the fancy pants AjaxFileUploader

Ok, if you want a simple async file upload, then use the AsyncFileUpload control from the AJ toolkit.

Do NOT place this inside of a update panel.

The AsyncFileUpload does NOT do a post-back and hence ZERO need exists for using a update panel.

So, your markup can be this:

```
        <ajaxToolkit:AsyncFileUpload ID="AsyncFileUpload1" runat="server" 
            OnUploadedComplete="AsyncFileUpload1_UploadedComplete" />
```

And code behind can be this:

```
        Debug.Print("up load done file = " + AsyncFileUpload1.FileName);

        string SaveFile = Server.MapPath(@"~/Files/") + AsyncFileUpload1.FileName;

        AsyncFileUpload1.SaveAs(SaveFile);
```

So, the above will NOT trigger a post-back at all.

(user does not hit a submit button).

Comment: I tried to use AsyncFileUpload control instead of  AjaxFileUpload from that toolkit cause I need only a simple fileupload but it does not work in asyncpostbacktrigger only in postbacktrigger so the same problem happened. I post a question about it...

Comment: See my example edit and use of AsyncFileUpload. Since it does NOT do a post-back, then you don't want to place the control in a update panel. However, if for some strange reason you do, then the control does work inside of a update panel. Remember, with the AsyncFileUpload control you do NOT need nor want a submit button - it up-loads automatic, and does so without a button click to post back the page.

Comment: Keep in mind that with this control, page load will fire before the complete event, so any code you have in page load needs to be placed in a If (!isPostBack) code block.